# How to Sum the values of a field based on month and year?

Tags: crystal-reports

[Crystal Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDz6U.png)

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tntzJ.png)

The report shown have two fields month and year. How can I sum the values of Count field after every month?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Running Total Field that available at the field explorer

1) The name of the field. Let say {Table A.Count}

2) Choose SUM